Alpine Linux - not booting after single partition install
I'd like to know correct, working way to setup Alpine Linux to single partition.
Not default BOOT+ROOT+SWAP but only single root partition (/)
This is test in VirtualBox but I'd like to try it later on old  32bit pc.
What I made:

256mb vhd
boot alpine-extended-3.20.3-x86.iso
apk add cfdisk e2fsprogs
create partition in cfdisk & set bootable
mkfs.ext2 /dev/sda1
apk del cfdisk e2fsprogs
mount -t ext2 /dev/sda1 /mnt
setup-alpine (skip disk setup)
setup-disk -m sys /mnt

And I get "You must fix mbr"
So I use again in livecd Alpine

apk add syslinux
dd bs=440 count=1 conv=notrunc if=/usr/share/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda

and after reboot still is Missing operating system.
(i have backup of VHD just after setup-disk)
Also tried to install from Windows with freeware program called Bootice (it can write mbr directly to VHD)
here is screenshot of MBR syslinux mbr Alpine
What should I do to make system bootable?

EDIT: I tried different method by using Grub2 bootloader instead of syslinux.
export BOOTLOADER=grub
apk add cfdisk e2fsprogs e2fsprogs-extra
cfdisk - make partition and set bootable

mkfs.ext2/3/4 /dev/sda1
e2label /dev/sda1 ALPINE   #label partition (not needed)

mount -t ext2 /dev/sda1 /mnt
apk del cfdisk e2fsprogs e2fsprogs-extra

setup-alpine 
setup-disk -m sys /mnt

apk add grub
grub-install --root-directory /mnt --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda

And after that Alpine Linux booted to bootloader, but next it's not loading. I get error:
mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /sysroot failed: No such device
Mounting root failed
initramfs emergency recovery shell lunched. Type exit...
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off.

So i typed exit.
After that I get this kernel-panic error: VirtualBox Alpine Kernel Panic
What I am doing wrong?

Alpine works correctly from live so it's not wrong configured VM.
And I checked, I have correct UUID in (/mnt) /etc/fstab
And on default partitioning scheme it was boot correctly.
Also it setup correctly when I use this before setup-alpine:
export BOOTFS=ext2 
export ROOTFS=ext2 
export BOOT_SIZE=100 
export SWAP_SIZE=0 

But unfortunetly BOOT_SIZE=0 did not work, so I can't disable creating boot partition

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
